# Check status of GMediaRenderer

Tags: bash, upnp

I use GMediaRenderer to send audio via UPNP from a Raspberry Pi. Occasionally, for reasons unknown, I have to SSH into my Pi and send the command `sudo service gmediarenderer restart` to get it to work properly. I'd like to add a command to `crontab` or similar that periodically checks whether the service is running *properly*. I already have a `crontab` entry that checks whether the service is running, and starts if it isn't. The trouble I'm having is that sometimes, even though the service is *running*, it doesn't appear to be communicating with UPNP control points. Executing the `restart` command brings it back, so I assume it is simply the case that the service has crashed but not closed down.

Does anyone know how to programmatically check (preferably using a bash script) whether the GMediaRenderer service is up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. The command `gssdp-discover` returns a list of active renderers. I setup a `sudo crontab` job to run a bash script every minute that checks whether or not a particular renderer is running, and to restart gmediarenderer if it isn't found.

The following command will list your active renderers:

```
gssdp-discover -i wlan0  --timeout=3
```

Change `wlan0` above depending on your specific network connection. In my case, the renderer that I'm interested in is listed as `urn:av-openhome-org:service:Info:1` (run the command with and without the renderer active, and look for the one that only appears when running). So, my bash script contains the following:

```
gssdp-discover -i wlan0  --timeout=3 --target=urn:av-openhome-org:service:Info:1 | grep available &> /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "OpenHome renderer is already running"
else
   echo "restarting gmediarenderer"
   /etc/init.d/gmediarenderer stop
   /etc/init.d/gmediarenderer start
fi
```